# C# Writing a file

Tags: c#, save

I've just got a quick question: I know how to write a file, but what would be the best way to store data in a file without it being readable as a text file?

Comment: do you want to encrypt it?

Comment: It doesn't have to be encrypted, but if that is the only way... PS. I already know how to encrypt stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either encrypt it, or store it in a binary file. I would recommend the first option ;)

Comment: thanks! I really needed that

Comment: @thijmen321, your post indicates you already know how to encrypt stuff - and yet this answer solved your problem.  I'm somewhat confused...

Comment: I didn't know you had to encrypt it...